# Extracting values next to specific words in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: function, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I got a string of data typed in a single cell like this "TIME200629 SYNC-7 CPU13.6", and I am trying to extract values next to the word TIME, SYNC, CPU in separate cells(2020-06-29 10:41:02 in C126, -7 in D126 and 13.6 in E126). What kind of functions or formula can I use to do this?

I can change the original form of string of data(Data(in)) if it is necessary to pull this off.

[image: example picture]

Comment: You can use various string functions or google's version of regular expressions to extract the necessary components.  And it would be simpler if your strings all had the same format, unlike your typed example vs the example in your screenshot, which are not.

Comment: Is the string always of fixed format so that the time will be "07:02:09" as an example and CPU is "13.0" instead of "13"? If yes then use left(), mid() and right().

Comment: if the strings has a delimiter like this: | or this ; or this , you can also use the "Text-to-Columns" https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/use-text-columns-excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your pattern words are only capitalized letters, and no other punctuation, then

In Sheets, you could do something like:

```
B2:  original string
C2:  =trim(REGEXEXTRACT($B2,C$1 & "([^A-Z]+)"))
    
   *and fill right to E2*
```

Adjust the cell references to suit.

[image]

Comment: I actually want to extract number beside the capitalized words. 
So in my example I need to have "2020-06-29 10:41:02" in C126, "-4" in D126 and "13.6 in E126

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be:

```
=SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(B126,"\s*[A-Z]+\s*","|"),"|")
```

This will spill to the right, and if you want you can include `ARRAYFORMULA` to splill to the bottom to, e.g.: `=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(B126:B127,"\s*[A-Z]+\s*","|"),"|"))`